# Calling a function (linked in C)

Tags: c

I'm trying to call a function from a .h and another .c file

trying to call the function in a line like this:
 image = getImage(filename,&dim);

I have defined image at the top of main function as,

```
QTnode* image;
```

from the struct

```
struct imgnode{
    int numb;  //number of the image
    int dim;   //dimension of the image
    char filename[20];  //name of file
    QTnode *qt;
    Imgnode *next;
    Imgnode *prev;
};
```

the function is in another .h called

```
QTnode *getImage(char *filename, int *dim );
```

but the compiler tells me filename is undeclared. Any help?

Comment: What is the compiler error exacly?

Comment: You said "filname is undeclared".  I fixed it to "filename is undeclared" (with some other cleanup).

Answer (score 2):

LOL i helped my friend working on this yesterday. COMP1917 assignment hmm?

you are supposed to pass in the filename you read from the stdin rather than the filename in the struct in this assignment

Back to C, defining a structure doesn't mean that you have that structure and have those members inside the structure. You still declare and create a structure instance by doing this:

```
struct imgnode node;
```

then you can access the member by doing this:

```
node.filename
```

or more commonly:

```
struct imgnode* nodePtr;
nodePtr->filename
```

Comment: yeah comp1917 assignemnt, i m confused.

my struct looks like this


struct imgnode{
 int numb;  //number of the image
 int dim;   //dimension of the image
 char fname[20];  //name of file
 QTnode *qt;
 Imgnode *next;
 Imgnode *prev;
};

Comment: can you provide a bit more basic instructions for a n00b like me, i m not understanding what you been

Answer (score 1):

```
image = getImage(filename,&dim);
              // ^^^^^^^^ Check where this variable declared.
              // If declared check whether it is accessible from this scope.
```

Compiler don't know what the variable `filename` being passed an argument in the current translation unit. `filename` should be some where declared and should be accessible at the point of the function call. Check it.

If you are trying to access the struct members then you should have instance to access them.

```
 image = getImage(strucInstance.filename,&(strucInstance.dim) );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you usually do is something like this

So you have a function defined in foo.c as

```
void foo()
{
    /* do nothing */
}
```

You put this line in a header file - guarded by include guards

```
void foo();
```

Now you include that header file in your other c file and the function should be able to resolve at compile time

Comment: It's not the function that's unresolved, it's the identifier `filename`.